# SSRS - MySQL - Stored Procedure - Support for schemas is disabled by NO_SCHEMA option, but non-empty schema is specified

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, odbc

In SSRS, I am trying to create a dataset from MySQL Datasource(stored proc). However getting below error,

### *TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer

### An error occurred while retrieving the parameters in the query.
ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-8.0.21-2]Support for schemas is disabled by NO_SCHEMA option, but non-empty schema is specified.*

The stored proc runs fine on MySQL Workbench 6.2. MySQL server version I have is 8.0.21-2.
I have MySQL ODBC 8.0 driver installed and I have tried to create connection with both ANSI/Unicode drivers. Getting same error with both. Also I have tested connection, it is working fine as I am able to create dataset with embedded query. The only issue is with creating dataset with stored proc.
If you had this issue and know how to resolve it then please guide me.

My Sp looks like below,

```html
CREATE  PROCEDURE `currentmonth`()

BEGIN

DECLARE StartDateTime datetime; -- default '1950-10-01 12:00:00';

DECLARE EndDateTime   datetime; -- default '1950-10-01 12:00:00';


SET StartDateTime ='1950-10-01 12:00:00'

SET EndDateTime   = '1950-10-01 12:00:00'


--SP Body here which is simple select
   

END
```

Thanks
Saqib H.

Comment: Please add mysql version(in addition to mysqlworkbench version) and sql-server version.

Comment: I have added mysql server version